# Deriving output filename from another parameter in Python Script Tool?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, parameters

In an ArcGIS Toolbox script tool, how can I get the default value for one parameter to be derived from the value of another parameter?

[GPX To Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/gpx-to-features.htm) does this, but I haven't been able to figure out how. There is logic under *Tool >> Properties >> Validation* to sanitize the filename but nothing about setting a default value. I've copied the validation code verbatim into my tool but that doesn't work.

[image: GPX to Features tool dialog with derived value shown]
[image: Tool validation code]

Answer (score 3):

This has had me spinning my wheels on and off for years. I didn't see what was wrong because I was always looking a layer deeper, into the code of the validation class and in the script.

The solution is simple: Remember to **set the *direction* of the output parameter**!

[image]